# I'm using React front-end and trying to fetch a video from my server via streaming but it doesn't work, why?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I've been trying to stream a video from my backend (locally) but it's not working as expected. I'm using a React front-end and making a fetch request but for some reason it doesn't work when I include a 1mb byte range (bytes=0-1048576) in the request header but it does work when I leave the range open ended (bytes=0-) because it's grabbing the entire video (not ideal). I'm thinking it has something do with my controller but I really can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Front-end

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Carousel, CarouselItem,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BiLogoImdb } from "react-icons/bi";
import NLDP from '../NLD/NLDP.jpg';
import GR from '../NLD/GR.jpeg';
import DJ from '../NLD/DJ.jpeg';
import JO from '../NLD/JO.jpeg';
import  RatedRSVG from '../../../../assets/MediaPrimary/RATED_R.svg';

function NLDPlayer() {
  const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const handleVideoPlay = () => {
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  const fetchVideo = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/NLDRoute', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'video/mp4',
          'Range': 'bytes=0-1048576',
        },
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
  
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (contentType && contentType.startsWith('video')) {
        const videoBlob = await response.blob();
        setVideoUrl(URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob));
        console.log('New chunk of video loaded');
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected response type:', contentType);
        setError(new Error('Unexpected response type'));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching video URL:', error);
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Fetching video..');
    fetchVideo();

}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {error ? (
        <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
      ) : (
        <>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          {!isPlaying ? (
               <div> 
               <div className='row align-items-center' style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
               <div className='col-5'>
                 <div className='page-content'>
                   <Card>
                   <h2 className='nld-font'>
                   Night of the Living Dead
                </h2>
                     <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                       <img
                         src={RatedRSVG}
                         alt="Rated R Symbol"
                         style={{
                           width: '3.2vw',
                           height: '3.2vh',
                           marginRight: '12px',
                         }}
                       />
                       <Card.Text>1968 1h 36m</Card.Text>
                     </div>
                     <Card.Text style={{ marginTop: '2vmin' }}>
                     A group of survivors barricade themselves 
                  in an old farmhouse to remain safe from 
                  a horde of flesh-eating zombies.
                     </Card.Text>
                     <Button
                       style={{
                         position: 'relative',
                         width: '20vmin',
                         height: '5.5vmin',
                         marginLeft: '10.5vmin',
                         marginTop: '2.5vmin',
                         transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                         fontSize: '2vmin',
                         backgroundColor: 'rgb(67, 66, 66)',
                         border: 'none',
                         cursor: 'pointer',
                       }}

                       onClick={handleVideoPlay}
                     >
                       ▶️ Play
                     </Button>
                     <div className="card-body-page">
                       <div className='row align-items-center'>
                         <div className='col-4'>
                           <h5>Director</h5>
                           <p>George Romero</p>
                         </div>
                         <div className='col-8'>
                           <h5>Cast</h5>
                           <p>Duane Jones, Russell Streiner, Judith O'Dea</p>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </Card>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div className='col-7' style={{ position: 'relative', backgroundColor: 'black', }}>
                 <img
                   src={NLDP}
                   alt="Poster Image"
                   style={{
                     width: '100%',
                     height: '100%',
                     marginBottom: '1%',
                     maskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                     WebkitMaskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                     transition: 'mask-image 0.3s ease',
                   }}
                   onClick={handleVideoPlay}
                 />
               </div>
               <div>
                </div>
                </div>
               <Card className="container card-body"
                    style={{
                      width: '100%',
                      height: '100%',
                      marginTop: '2%',
                      marginBottom: '1%',
                     
                    }}>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                      <h2 className='justify-content-center'>About</h2>
                      </div>
                      <div>
          <Card className='about-card'> 
        <div className='row align-items-center'>
          <div className='col-8'> 
          <div> 
          <Card style={{padding:'2%',}}>
              <h3>Director</h3>
              <h4>
                George Romero</h4>
              <Card.Text>
              George A. Romero never set out to become a Hollywood figure; by all indications, 
              though, he was very successful. The director of the groundbreaking "Living Dead" 
              films was born February 4, 1940 ,in New York City to Ann (Dvorsky) and Jorge Romero. 
              His father was born in Spain and raised in Cuba, and his mother was Lithuanian. 
               He and his friends formed Image Ten Productions in the late 1960s 
              and they all chipped in roughly $10,000 apiece to produce what became one of the 
              most celebrated American horror films of all time: Night of the Living Dead (1968). 
              Shot in black-and-white on a budget of just over $100,000, Romero's vision, combined 
              with a solid script written by him and his "Image" co-founder John A. Russo, enabled the film to earn back 
              far more than what it cost; it became a cult classic by the early 1970s and was inducted 
              into the National Film Registry of the Library of Congress of the United States in 1999. Like almost 
              all of his films, they were shot in, or around, Romero's favorite city of Pittsburgh.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-4' style={{position:'relative',}}>
              <img  
                src={GR} 
                alt='george romero' 
                className="img-fluid" 
                style={{
                  width: '60%',
                  height: '60%',
                  maskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                  WebkitMaskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                  transition: 'mask-image 0.3s ease',
                }}
                />
                <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001681/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1">
            <BiLogoImdb style={{ color: 'gold', fontSize: '4.5vmin' }} />
          </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </Card>
            </div>
    <div className='card-body-cast'> 
            <h3 style={{marginLeft:'2%', marginTop: '2%',}}>Cast</h3>
         <div>
          <Carousel>
            <CarouselItem>
            <Card> 
        <div className='row align-items-center'>
          <div className='col-7'> 
          <div> 
          <Card style={{padding:'2%',}}>
              
              <h4>
                Duane Jones</h4>
              <Card.Text>
              Cult figure who will forever be remembered as Ben, the resourceful, 
              yet ill-fated hero of George A. Romero's low-budget zombie film 
              Night of the Living Dead (1968). Jones was a former English professor 
              who directed at the Maguire Theater at the Old Westbury campus of 
              New York State University, and he additionally served as artistic 
              director at the Richard Allen Center in New York City. His casting 
              as the hero of the Romero film was unique, as it was the first occasion 
              that an African-American actor had portrayed the hero in a horror film. 
              The tall, talented Jones appeared in a handful of other B-grade horror 
              movies such as Ganja & Hess (1973) and Vampires (1986), but none are 
              remembered as well as his first on-screen role.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-4' style={{position:'relative',}}>
              <img  
                src={DJ} 
                alt='Duane Jones' 
                className="img-fluid" 
                style={{
                  width: '65%',
                  height: '65%',
                  maskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                  WebkitMaskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                  transition: 'mask-image 0.3s ease',
                }}
                />
                 <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0427977/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1">
            <BiLogoImdb style={{ color: 'gold', fontSize: '4.5vmin' }} />
          </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </Card>
            </CarouselItem>
            <CarouselItem>
            <Card> 
        <div className='row align-items-center'>
          <div className='col-7'> 
          <div> 
          <Card style={{padding:'2%',}}>
              <h4>
              Judith O'Dea </h4>
              <Card.Text>
              Judith O'Dea is an American actress. She is best known for 
              the 1968 George A. Romero film Night of the Living Dead. 
              In the 1980s she put her acting career aside to found her 
              coaching company O'Dea Communications and raise her family. 
              She reappeared again as an actress on 2003 in the horror film 
              Claustrophobia. In 2017 she reprised the role of Barbra Hamilton 
              in the film Night of the Living Dead: Genesis.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-4' style={{position:'relative',}}>
              <img  
                src={JO} 
                alt='Derrick De Marney' 
                className="img-fluid" 
                style={{
                  width: '65%',
                  height: '65%',
                  maskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                  WebkitMaskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent)',
                  transition: 'mask-image 0.3s ease',
                }}
                />
                 <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0640621/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_7_tt_1_nm_7_q_judith%2520od">
            <BiLogoImdb style={{ color: 'gold', fontSize: '4.5vmin' }} />
          </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </Card>
            </CarouselItem>
          </Carousel>
          
            </div>
            </div>
            <div> 
            </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </Card>
            <Card className="container"
                    style={{
                      width: '100%',
                      height: '100%',
                      marginTop: '10%',
                      marginBottom: '10%',
                     
                    }}>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                      
                      </div>
                    <div >
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </Card>
            </div>

          ) : (
            <div style={{ 
              display: 'flex', 
              justifyContent: 'center', 
              alignItems: 'center', 
              width: '100%', 
              height: '100%', 
              backgroundColor: 'black' }}> 
            <video 
              className='justify-items-center'
              src={videoUrl}
              controls
              playsInline
              loop
              autoPlay
              style={{ width: '100vmin', height: '100vmin', backgroundColor: 'black', }}
            />
            </div>
          )}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default NLDPlayer;
```

Back-end

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function serveVideo(req, res) {
  
  const videoPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../assets/NLD/NLD.mp4'); // Update the path to your video file
  console.log('Video path:', videoPath);

  const stat = fs.statSync(videoPath);
    const fileSize = stat.size;
    const range = req.headers.range;

    if(range){
        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-')
        console.log('Requested Range:', range);
        const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize - 1;

        const chunksize = end - start + 1;
        const file = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, {start, end});
        const head = {
            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
        };
        res.writeHead(206, head);
        file.pipe(res);
    }
}

module.exports = {
  serveVideo,
};
```

Server

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();
const db = require('./config/connection');

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
  credentials: true,
}));

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);


db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

try {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, () => {
    console.log(`API server running on port 3001`);
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.error(`Error while starting the server: ${err.message}`);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to force a request for only a chunk of your video?  Let the browser figure it out and make its own requests.  It knows what data it needs.  You're essentially corrupting the video by overriding this behavior.  Your videos are probably encoded in such a way that data at the end of the file is required.  (Hint: Use `-movflags faststart` with FFmpeg.)  Also, why are you writing all this code to handle the server-side?  Why not just use a normal web server and let it handle the response?  Or at least, let Express do it, which is well-tested.

Comment: Also, when making posts on Stack Overflow, you should really pare down your question to a relevant code snippet.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the input. I included all of the code relevant to this operation because there are pieces of it not directly related to the immediate snippet which might be affecting the behavior. Also, if someone wants to replicate this scenario on their machine, they can do so more easily. Some people prefer this. Does that make sense?  Regarding the stream, the reason why I'm grabbing the video in chunks is because this is what streaming content involves; rather than getting the entire video all at once thereby increasing lag time, the front-end grabs 1mb of data on a continuous basis.

Comment: The browser will handle that buffering for you though.  There's no reason to do it yourself.  It knows the state of what's playing on the page, an estimate of how much bandwidth is available, how much memory and cache storage are available, and uses this information to determine what to buffer to ensure smooth playback for the user.  You don't need to do any of that... just set the appropriate `src` for the media element.  It doesn't just fetch the entire video at once.  TCP window sizing comes into play.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you're saying now. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Found the solution. Instead of making a fetch request, the video is referenced using <source>. Everything else remains the same.  `  <video
              ref={(videoRef) => {
                if (videoRef) {
                  videoRef.pause();
                  videoRef.removeAttribute('src');
                  videoRef.load();
                }
              }}
            >
              <source src={`https://second-team-productions.onrender.com/NLDRoute`} type='video/mp4'></source>
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>' `